# How can I connect docker container use localhost?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I created a docker-container based on nodejs. However, it seems to run fine, but both localhost:8080 and localhost:8443 and localhost can't connect. Also, the connection using curl produces the following message:

```
$ curl -vvv localhost:8080
*   Trying ::1:8080...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.67.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
$ curl -vvv localhost:8443
*   Trying ::1:8443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8443 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8443
> User-Agent: curl/7.67.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

This is docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    container_name: app_test
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8443:8443"
```

This is Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.12.0

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80 # I try 3000, 8080 instead 80

CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

And This is result of `docker ps`

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                    NAMES
735fba0a6ff5        IMAGE_NAME                  "node app.js"            46 seconds ago      Up 45 seconds       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp   app_test
```

Neither curl nor browser runs. What should I do?

(I'm awkward because I'm not good at English. Please understand.)

Comment: You're node app is probably serving at port 3000?

Comment: @QuintenScheppermans 
This is ./bin/www
If you look below it is connected to 3000.
`var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);`

Comment: Have you tried to add from your docker-compose file:  ports:
      - "80:3000"

Answer (score 4):

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    container_name: app_test
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:3000"
      - "8443:8443"
```

If you want access your app on localhost:8080, 
this should work. A node app serves on port 3000 as standard.

So basically:

**{port host machine}**:**{port it actually runs on inside your container}**

Comment: I did try that. But result is same. Port part of the `docker ps` result `0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->3000/tcp`

Comment: What happens if you exec the command from within the container? "docker exec -it app_test bash" will open a shell, curl localhost:3000 there and tell me what happens.

Comment: Oh! restart docker and then process was successfully! Thank you.

Comment: @DOYEOPKIM , Please mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem.

Comment: This answer fixed my problem. It should be the correct answer.